# How to determine if I'm selecting multiple or a single element with document.querySelector

Tags: javascript, dom, jquery-selectors, selectors-api

I'm writing a function `$` (similar to one of jQuery's `$`), but with non-jQuery methods and helpers, with plain DOM properties.

I have stucked at determining if I'm selecting multiple elements by a given selector or just a single element.

So far I have wrote this and I would like to know if there's a possibility to write this with less code and maybe only using only-one of the methods from DOM: `querySelector` or `querySelectorAll`.

```
String.prototype.startsWith = function( offset ) {
    var _offset = 1;

    if( offset !== undefined ) {
        _offset = offset;
    }

    return this.substr(0, _offset);
}

function $( selector ) {
    if( selector.startsWith() == '#') {
        return document.querySelector( selector );
    } else {
        return document.querySelectorAll( selector );
    }
}
```

**How can we reduce the code of this?**

Answer (score 1):

```
function (selector) {
    return document[selector[0] === '#' ? 
          'querySelector' : 
          'querySelectorAll'](selector)
}
```

Or you can do this:

```
function (selector) {
    var result = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
    if(result.length === 1)
        return result[0];
    return result;
}
```

**EDIT** jquery selectors always return array like object despite of item count in it, so what you are trying to do is different from jQuery behaviour